# Power BI slicer filter on FK field on power bi report

Tags: powerbi

Let's suppose this data structure:

- Customers (cust_id and cust_name)
- Invoices (invoice_id, cust_id, date)

I want to show invoices in a table component on a report.

I have add a slicer, because i want to filter this table by customer.
I have dragged Invoces > cust_id field into this slicer.

What i want to do is to display cust_name into this slicer.
How can i do this ?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with "segment"? which visual are you using?

Comment: I am sorry, the english version is Slicer. See my edit

Comment: A slicer can only contain one column, you must create a new one (or edit the current one) to display the "cust_name". if you want to display both "id" and "name" in the same slicer you must create a calculated column in DAX

Comment: I want to display one column: cust_name. But i need to store id, because this is id which is applied on filter

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your requirement. If you linked your data properly in the data model you can use the customer name in the filter and it will propagate to the invoices table. If instead, you need to show the name of the selected customer you can use a "card" visual (therefore you will have a slicer with "id", and a card with the name of the selected customer), this works best if only one customer is selected at a time

Comment: When you say "Linked data properly", do you mean foreign keys at database level ? Or is there a link to do  in power bi ?

Comment: connect these tables by customer id in your data model in power bi. Then put customer name on a slicer.